# errno 90 message too long on recv when ICMP destination unreachable packet arrives

Tags: sockets, recv, icmp

I am reading data from a socket with recv function and keep getting error when I receive ICMP destination unreachable packet. I truly don't know where the problem is. I tried setting the socket to different options but none of them worked for me. I use RAW socket.

Here is my setsockopt:

```
setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, (char *)&optval, sizeof(optval))
```

optval is set to 1

here is my recv:

```
    // read response from socket
    if ((len = recv(sock, buffer, BUFFER_MAX, 0)) == -1) 
      fprintf(stderr,"Error with reading data - %d\n",errno);
```

BUFFER_MAX is defined as 65536

If somebody has met with similar problem, could  you please explain me there is always errno code 90, when trying to recieve ICMP dest. unreachable packet? ECHO reply works fine.

Comment: try `MSG_TRUNC` and check size

Comment: also tried, didn't work.
I checked it in wireshark - the packets keep coming, I can see them clearly recieved, but the recv throws always error.

Comment: just wild guesses from here, have you verified the return value of all your syscalls (eg: setsockopt)?

Comment: yes, i check the return value everywhere

Comment: Okay, i have found the answer - i must use functions sendto, recvfrom and gethostbyname (of course without connect()). Otherwise i could not join the correct destination address to my socket.
I may have mistaken the structures and the previous solution may be right.